# asp.net MVC 4 webgrid with an IF statement

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I have a column that needs to check a field of the object, when the field equals 2 then another has to multiply with -1.

The problem is I do not know the syntax to do this inside the creation of my gridview. Could someone give an example how this works?

```
        @(invoice.dc.Equals(2)?String.Format("{0:0.00}", invoice.totv * -1): String.Format("{0:0.00}", invoice.totv))
```

This code sample i have to accomplish inside the creation of the gridview. So if field: dc equals 2 show invoice.totv * -1 else show invoice.totv.

This is what i have tried:

```
grid.Column("", "PDF", format: 
        (item) => if(@item.dc == 2)
        {
            String.Format("{0:0.00}", @item.totv * -1)  ;   
        }
        else
        {
            String.Format("{0:0.00}", @item.totv)  ;

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
grid.Column("", "PDF", (item) => String.Format("{0:0.00}", item.dc == 2 ? item.totv * -1 : item.totv));
```

Comment: When I use this code I cannot sort anymore? Any workarounds? thx for responding

Comment: You don't mention anything about sorting in your question, I thought this was purely a formatting/syntax problem.

Comment: I thought working with gridview in asp.net would always give the option of sorting. Is it possible to add the sorting again?

Comment: Of course, see [Sorting Data in a GridView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwf94875(v=vs.100).aspx)